# Back button and browser

Tags: android, cordova

I have an application in which I use an ads library, this library opens ads links directly on the browser, the problem is:

On Android, when I return to my application and press the back button instead of returning to the previous page, it immediately closes the application

Does anyone have a solution to this problem and how adjust it?

Comment: which lib you have used

Comment: Plugin of applovin

Comment: you need to override onbackPress, and check if the ad is displaying then hide the ad else call super

Answer (score 0):

you should call `onBackPress`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
       // you can set your config
    }
```

and You have probably finished the previous page

Answer (score 0):

You need to have an override function of onBackPressd() inOrder to use the back fumctionality otherwise it will just close the window on Back press

Use the following Code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```